# Parse.com iOS SDK: Create New Related Object on Object Save

Tags: database, events, parse-platform

I'm trying to use cloud code to create a new 'credit' every time a new `User` is created, the credit is for that user, as in it is a related object. For some reason I can't get writing to the 'Logs' tab to work using lines like `console.log(tell me what is going on!);` so I'm stumped, and with no way of knowing where I've gone wrong.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("User", function(request) {
    var Credit = Parse.Object.extend("credit");
    var credit = new Credit();

    credit.set("parent", request.object);
    credit.set("expiry", null);
    credit.set("type", "Opening");

    credit.save();
});
```

Comment: You might also want to check the `isNew()` property on the user so you only do it on Create and not on Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it to this:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request)
```

`Parse.User` rather than `"User"`.

For whatever reason this doesn't seem to be in the docs here: https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave

Comment: It's mentioned in the last paragraph of this section: https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave

Comment: So it is... How annoying, not sure how I missed that.